# Can A Shear Transformation be Represented as A Change To A Function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Ok I'm going to make the question a bit more specific now. When learning about graphs of functions, I learnt about certain transformations that could be applied to them. Example below.

[image: Horizontal shift 5 units]

y = x^2

(shifted 5 units left becomes)

y = (x+5)^2

By adding 5 to x we can represent the translation of the graph. (This is what I will call a **Cartesian Form of a Transformation**, this is not a standard term)

Later on I learnt about the Matrix representation of transformations. Example below

[image: A Shear Transformation shown in Matrix Form]

Is there any way to represent this shear transformation in a Cartesian form. That is can I express this transformation as a change to a function (adding some values to the x part)?

**An Example Of A Matrix Transformation In Cartesian Form**

Consider a reflection around the y-axis.

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & -1  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

This could be represented in "Cartesian Form" by negating the y-value of this function.

E.g:

y = x^2
Becomes
y = -(x^2)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'Cartesian form'? How is a shear transformation defined?

Comment: Give example of something that you think it is a Cartesian form, what ever that means

Comment: If you add $bx$ to a function of $x$ the graph of the new function will be a shear of the graph of the original function. Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: Kind of, I'm asking IF a shear can represented that way. Vertical Translation can be shown by adding a constant to the function. y = x^2 -> y=x^2 +5. That's pretty simple but can something like a shear transformation be represented as this modification to a function. If not it's ok I'm just wondering.